# Android - Zooming Issue on project

Tags: java, android

I'm working on this project which involves a map with pins on it that populate from a database.  The idea was to click on the map and the pin would pull up information, I have all of this working. I position these with a relative layout and the pin inside this.

Where my problem lies is, I have a pinch to zoom and all that on here and when I zoom on the image, my pins stay in their original position.  Is there anyway I can have these pins zoom in when the image is zoomed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would look into placing the Pins onto the map via an exact location (eg latitude and Longitude) and then the pin always being the same size image this when the map zooms the pin is relative to an exact position there for moving with the image below.

another eg would be locating the pin on pixles 100 right and 50 down.

Comment: Let me explain whats going on a bit more.  I said map, but really what it is, is an image of a map, nothing to do with real lat/long.  Everything looks okay until I try to zoom, the map zooms in, but the pins which are on top of the image are not zooming in.  Basically I need a way to make a relationship between the map and the pins when zooming so they scale the same.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of an HTML map like element in an Android View:

Supports images as drawable or bitmap in layout
Allows for a list of area tags in xml
Enables use of cut and paste HTML area tags to a resource xml (ie, the ability to take an HTML map - and image and use it with minimal editing)
Supports panning if the image is larger than the device screen
Supports pinch-zoom
Supports callbacks when an area is tapped.
Supports showing annotations as bubble text and provide callback if the bubble is tapped
try this link you will find your solution https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap